# INSERT existing values into new column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql

I've created a new column (column4) on an existing table that I have filled with all nulls. I'm trying to populate all the records with existing values from a linked server column. The values that are inserted have to match the correct row.

This is as close as I've seem to come however I'm now receiving the below error. I'm not even trying to update that column. I'm only referencing that so the new value knows where to put the inserted values.

```
INSERT INTO Server1.database.schema.table1 (Column4)
SELECT link.column6
FROM LinkedServer.database.schema.view as link
INNER JOIN Server1.database.schema.table1 as local
ON link.key = local.key
WHERE local.key = link.key
```

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 212
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'key', table 'local'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Comment: You've tagged this with several different database products. Don't do this. Choose the product you're using, otherwise you're just wasting people's time, as different flavours of RDBMS frequently use different syntax.. From the error message you're not using Oracle so why include it in the scope of your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sql server, you would need to use an `update` instead of `insert`.

```
update local
set local.Column4 = link.column6
from LinkedServer.database.schema.view link
  inner join Server1.database.schema.table1 local
    on link.key = local.key
```

Comment: @Rahul The error message is from sql server, so I went with that.

Comment: Yeah .. LOL, OP has tagged all available RDBMS. So the comment is specific for that. I believe you should mention that in answer for clarification

Comment: @Rahul Updated to mention that the answer is for sql server.